# TH element not fitting new image size

Tags: html, css, image, size, scale

I have an image contained inside a  element. I scaled the image to 25% using css. Now, however, the  element width didn't change. Help would be appreciated. I want the  elemnent's width, to match the width of the image. If this isn't possible with css, I can just use JavaScript. Thanks

html

```css
form {
  padding-left: 10px
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #CDCDCD
}

.imageContain {
  display: inline-block;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<h1>Data Calculator (Mean, Median, Mode, Range, and Average)</h1>
<table align="center">
  <th>
    <div>
      <label>Put numbers here. Separated by a space</label><br>
      <input id="input" />
      <br>
      <select id="selection">
        <option value="mean">Mean</option>
        <option value="median">Median</option>
        <option value="mode">Mode</option>
        <option value="range">Range</option>
        <option value="average">Average</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button id="output" onclick="submit()">Output</button><br>
      <label id="result"><label>
        </div>
    </th>

    <th>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dHhcc5a_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" style="max-width:25%">
    </th>
</table>
```

Comment: 25% of what? That's what the width refers to.

Comment: Doesn’t it mean 25% of the original width?

Comment: Not usually, it means % of the parent.

Comment: Why are you using a th for this? (or 2?) Your content  does not consist of headings. Use a table row (tr) and use cells (tds) instead of a div and a second th. Also, your label isn't closed properly, missing a closing slash

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-color: #CDCDCD
}form {
  padding-left: 10px
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.box{
    width: 20rem;
    height: 22rem;
}
label{
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 30px!important;
}
input{
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px ;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
select{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
button{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.img-th{
    border: none;
}
th img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Data Calculator (Mean, Median, Mode, Range, and Average)</h1>
<table align="center">
  <th>
    <div class="box">
      <label>Put numbers here. Separated by a space</label><br>
      <input id="input" />
      <br>
      <select id="selection">
        <option value="mean">Mean</option>
        <option value="median">Median</option>
        <option value="mode">Mode</option>
        <option value="range">Range</option>
        <option value="average">Average</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button id="output" onclick="submit()">Output</button><br>
      <label id="result"><label>
        </div>
    </th>

    <th class="img-th"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/dHhcc5a_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand"></th>
</table>
```

[Is this your answer?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2jg.png)